What is the correct way for installing StrongSwan on Ubuntu 24-04 (ipsec.conf, NetworkManager, or...)
As I described in this question, I try to access my local network which is behind a VPN firewall from Ubuntu 24-04 via StrongSwan. I used /etc/ipsec.conf (strongswan libcharon-extra-plugins).
Except of  some problems with DNS, I got it working. However, on the way on getting it to work, I also learned, that there is a StrongSwan plugin for Ubuntu's Network Manger. I also tried to make it working with that manager plugin (network-manager-strongswan), but I was not able to tell StrongSwan to accept the self signed certificate of my firewall (and was completely lost with the configuration, since there seem to be no configuration files, but some D-Bus-Magic).
And then I also found an article which stated, that ipsec.conf is very outdated, and that there is a much better and newer way to setup a StrongSwan VPN (-client).
As a total Linux beginner, I'm completely lost: What is nowadays the recommended way to setup a roadwarrior VPN with Ubuntu and StrongSwan. Is there a good explanation on how to do this?
Aa a sidenote: I cannot use Wireguard or OpenVPN, due to my Firewall.
